# Live CD 12:04 keeps running - No Welcome Screen

Tags: cd

I downloaded the 32 bit iso file for the new Ubuntu 12.04 and burned a cd. When I restart my computer the cd keeps running for half an hour but I don't get a welcome screen.

A new download and cd does not solve the problem. Upgrating from 11 to
12 does work without any problems but I want to install from scratch.

With best regards,
Edwin

Answer (score 0):

Do you see anything at all when booting to the cd? Did you try hitting ESC right when it starts up? Also, maybe you could try the alternate non-graphical installer. Other than that, maybe it's an acpi issue, or something that's plugged into your computer? If it's an acpi issue, you can temporarily get around that by either setting the f6 option to acpi=off, or if the option exists in the BIOS, you can turn it off there.

Comment: Thanks, I just see a blinking - left above at the screen. Cd keeps running. No respond on any key. I did not plugged any USB at my laptop. For previous versions not any problems.

Comment: When I click the escape button the computer just start up (I only have ubuntu 12:04 installed)

Comment: Just tried at another laptop. Same problem. Then on a desktop PC. Same problem but with the text "loding boot logo". Nothing happend, cd keeps running.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, and if you see a purple screen (seemingly blank) try hitting F6 and it will direct you to a menu. I don't know why that works, but that's what works for me.